# Is it possible to tell if a user is logged into Wordpress from looking at the cookies which are set?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, users, user-access, cookies

Is it possible to tell if a user is logged into Wordpress from looking at the cookies which are set on a site? If not, how could I add hooks to the login success and logout actions and set my own cookies?

Comment: It would help to actually know those reasons. People might not agree with them, but such things are relevant technically.

Comment: Downvotes are a hint that there are issues with a question as community sees it. You have my downvote now, since you stressed your attitude instead of fixing it.

Comment: Wouldn't be a downvote (from my side), if you'd have taken the time to illustrate your needs instead saying: "_I have my reasons and I don't care if you agree with them_". This doesn't help any further readers, which is the purpose of this Q/A format. If you'd explain the _why_, later readers might get better insights whether your problem is related to their own or not. Btw: The attitude is more than just harsh and really not appreciated.

Comment: @Rarst - you're right. I've reworded the question. My apologies.

Comment: @kaiser - you're right as well. I think I was frustrated by not being able to get Wordpress to work and should have spent more time on the question. I'm sorry and I've redone the question.

Comment: @cwd n/p Removed downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

var logged_in=getCookie("wordpress_logged_in_[HASH]");
  if (logged_in!=null && logged_in!="")
  {
  alert("You are logged in!");
  }
else
  {
   alert("You are logged out!");
  }
</script>
```

NOTE: Wordpress logged in cookie info can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies#WP_.3E_3). You'll need to figure out what your hash is and possibly use regex for the hash. (this is untested but should work)

[JS cookie source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)